# Using variadic template arguments for arbitrary number of classes

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have a situation where I need a class `FaceProp` that maintains/holds other classes for actual face types. These could be any types of faces like boundary faces, solid faces, internal faces etc etc. I wanted to implement `FaceProp` using the variadic parameter pack feature in C++, but I am not sure how this can be achieved.

I am attempting the following main class

```
 template<typename... FaceTypes>
 class FaceProp 

 {
     FaceProp(){
         /// here construct all those template argument classes. 
      }

  private:

   // declare here the classes to the FaceTypes.
   // e.g. If this class was declared with two face types I would have :
   //   std::unique_ptr<FaceType1> type1;
   //   std::unique_ptr<FaceType2> type2;

 }
```

I am not sure how declaring those would work since by the time of implementing I don't know how many/ and which face types I need to deal with. This is known by compiling time. In other words, when I want to declare the class `FaceProp` I would know how many face types to use

e.g.

```
 std::unique_ptr<FaceProp<facetype1, facetype2>> allfaces;
```

How is this best achieved?

Comment: I think this case may be better solved with interface.

Comment: But how are related the `FaceTypes` to `FaceProp`? `FaceProp` inherit from all `FaceTypes`? `FaceProp` must contain a `std::tuple<FaceTypes...>`? Or a `std::variant<FaceTypes...>`?

Comment: `std::tuple` is the way to go. Otherwise you essentially need to reimplement the tuple, which is not trivial.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you elaborate please? Also, do you have any good ref on variadic template argument, feel like I am not understanding the concept as I should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to do this using `std::tuple` as suggested in the comments. I showed it with and without `std::unique_ptr`.

```
template <typename... FaceTypes>
class FaceProp
{
   FaceProp() {
      m_tuple = {FaceTypes()...};
      m_uniqueTuples = {std::make_unique<FaceTypes>()...};
   }

private:
   std::tuple<FaceTypes...> m_tuple;
   std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<FaceTypes>...> m_uniqueTuples;
};
```

The `...` in the code expands the associated expression to include each type in the parameter pack. So, `FaceProp<int, double>` expands to:

```
class FaceProp
{
   FaceProp() {
      m_tuple = {int(), double()};
      m_uniqueTuples = {std::make_unique<int>(), std::make_unique<double>()};
   }

private:
   std::tuple<int, double> m_tuple;
   std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<double>> m_uniqueTuples;
};
```